# 9 patch drawable appears bad after cleaning and rebuilding project in a new android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, nine-patch

I have a 9 patch image file which am using in my android project. am using android studio 2.2 preview 3(the latest as per this question).

in layout design view, everything is ok. and when i installed on my device for first time, everything was ok. **But i later on clean and rebuilt my project** and the 9 patch appeared very very bad on my device while it appears well in layout design.

**In device(after clean and rebuilding my project)**

[image: bad]

**How it appears in my layout design**

[image]

**Note:** it used to appear good like the second image in my device before clean and rebuilding.

I have even tried to invalidate and restart android studio but with no success. what could be the cause and how can i solve this problem?

**EDIT**
my file is in drawable folder and it's name is left_2.9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the unstable gradle version `2.2.0-alpha3` which is found in android studio 2.2 preview 3. i changed my version to the stable version which is `2.1.0` and everything was ok.

to do this, i went to my project's `build.gradle` (**not module's build.gradle**) and changed

```
classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3
```

to

```
 classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file is saved as `<filename>.9.png` and not `<filename>.png`.

If you find this is an issue try building from the command line:

```
./gradlew clean installDebug
```

Comment: i have several modules on my project. how can i run the above command on the only module that am currently working on?

Comment: You should be able to prepend the name of the module, so if you only wanted to clean the app module you'd type `app:clean`. Why are you worried about cleaning the entire project?

Comment: because am getting TaskExcutionException when i clean the entire project